# How do I add .do (Stata) file extension to QuickLook in Mac OS 13?

Tags: stata, quicklook, macos-ventura

i got the problem that since the current update of MacOS to 13, the Quicklook does not support .do file from Stata anymore. It worked so far super fine till now.

I tried to add and altering QLStephen as well as QLColorCode.

First is used:
mdls -name kMDItemContentType /Users/konstantinromer/Documents/somestata.do
which resulted in:
kMDItemContentType = "com.stata.stata.do"

The problem is, that while adding this to QLColorCode, the plugin breaks. For QLStephen I tried it similarly.

Edit: Reinstalling StataMP did not help any further.

Comment: I'd take this to StataCorp Technical Services if you don't get a good answer.